# EF Core options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(true) causes problem with records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, .net-6.0

Since I changed my entities to be of record type I get an error when using lazy loading proxies.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(connection);
                    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(true);
                });
```

The error is:

Return type in method 'Castle.Proxies.ListViewConfigProxy.$()' on type 'Castle.Proxies.ListViewConfigProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with base type method 'Common.Models.Config.ListViewConfig.$()'.

With Lazy loading proxies enabled, it happens with every entity in every DB Context which is a record.

- Why and is there any solution besides not using records?
- Whats the problem with the record's Clone Method?

I am using NET 6 SDK (not tested with NET5)

Comment: For the record: no problems in EF-core 5. But it could be related to the model structure, so please post a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: We have just encountered the same problem with the released version of .NET 6 and which definitely did not occur on .NET 5.  We are trying to get to the bottom of it. So far we have seen it only where we have one record type inheriting from another.

Comment: We have now managed to create a minimal reproducible example of the problem, which (for us) requires these three conditions: 1) use  of record types 2) inheritance between record types 3) lazy loading.  We have lodged this as a bug report on the EF Core repository here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26714  - with links to the example projects.

Comment: @Richard-Pawson Nice job